# Command line arguments for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments

I am providing command line arguments as

```
python tenant_apps.py {dbname} {username} {owner} {project}
```

and inserting specific name for every argument. But the `owner` may have both first name and last name or just a single name and if they enter that... how can we make sure that it is taken as one argument? Same question applies to `project` too. For example `owner` can be `John Adams` or just `John`.

Comment: Use quotes when running the program. The program itself doesn't need to change.

Comment: How the shell passes arguments isn't your program's problem, nor is it even anything your program can control.

Comment: @zondo: Tried doing that...but then do I have to apply some condition for space between names because still its now working

Comment: Can you show me how you're running it (with an actual example that doesn't work.)

Comment: This **isn't actually a question about Python**; it's a question about the shell. Deciding which words go into which command-line arguments is done by the terminal, **before the program starts**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As zondo was saying, using quoted args on the command line will allow you to pass in a string containing spaces as a single argument.

Some simple code to demonstrate:

```
import sys
print("Commnd line arg values: %s" % sys.argv[1:])
```

Entering the following command line with some quoted parameters will give:

```
> python myscript.py aaa bbb "ccc ddd" eee "fff ggg hhh"
Commnd line arg values: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc ddd', 'eee', 'fff ggg hhh']
```

Comment: @zondo: Thank you :)